# Cannot read property "0" from undefined using RegEx

Tags: javascript

I write the the below code. But I got an error saying

> Cannot read property "0" from undefined at line 1.

Is there anything I missed in this line?

```
var code = "/[0-9]{6}/"; //<== This is line 1
var rgx = new SNC.Regex(code);
var sub = "6 Digit number: 123456";
var Matched = rgx.match(sub); 
if (JSUtil.notNil(Matched)) {
  var result = "Found";
}
```

Comment: That is not the "line 1" that the error is pointing to. That line evaluates just fine. Your error is elsewhere.

Comment: Are you somehow somewhere accessing a properties of an array? The error code doesn't make sense with the code you shared with us

Answer (score 1):

Try like this way, just need to do some tweaks on your existing code.

1. Remove this unnecessary line `var rgx = new SNC.Regex(code);`
2. Remove extra double quotes `"` from your regexp.
3. Use proper syntax for regex match in JS. Syntax is `str.match(regexp)`

**Ref.:** https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match

```js
var regexp = /[0-9]{6}/; //<== Remove QUOTES here 
var str = "6 Digit number: 123456";
var Matched = str.match(regexp); // <== str.match(regexp)
console.log(Matched); //just for debugging
if (Matched) {
  console.log("Found");
} else {
  console.log("Not Found");
}
```